# Demoted domain controller still authenticating users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, kerberos

Why is a demoted domain controller still authenticating users?

Whenever users log onto workstations with domain accounts, this demoted DC authenticates them. Its security log shows their logons, logoffs, and special logons. Our new DCs' security logs show some machine logons and logoffs, but nothing to do with domain users.

## Background

1. *server1* (Windows Server 2008): Recently demoted DC, file server
2. *server3* (Windows Server 2008 R2): New DC
3. *server4* (Windows Server 2008 R2): New DC

## Logs

Security Log Events: http://imgur.com/a/6cklL.

Two sample events from *server1*:

```
Audit Success,3/31/2014 11:06:14 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,4624,Logon,"An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\auser
    Account Name:       auser
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x8b792ce
    Logon GUID:     {54063226-E9B7-D357-AD58-546793C9CA59}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: 192.168.20.143
    Source Port:        52834

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Kerberos
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

[ ... ]

Audit Success,3/31/2014 11:06:06 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,4624,Logon,"An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\anotheruser
    Account Name:       anotheruser
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x8b74ea5
    Logon GUID:     {7E74986A-7A4D-B6E0-5D6F-D8CF78E8C718}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: 192.168.20.203
    Source Port:        53027

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Kerberos
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Sample *Audit Policy Change* event from *server3* (there are also *Audit Policy Change* events in the log with changes marked "Success Added"):

```
System audit policy was changed.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SERVER3$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Audit Policy Change:
    Category:       Account Logon
    Subcategory:        Kerberos Authentication Service
    Subcategory GUID:   {0cce9242-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030}
    Changes:        Success removed
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. **Fixing DNS entries.** `dcdiag /test:dns` at first returned errors after *server1* was demoted. There were outdated name server entries in our forward lookup zones, for example. I ended up opening DNS Manager and removing the problem entries manually, also ensuring that LDAP and Kerberos entries pointed to the new servers. For instance, __ldap.Default-First-Site.__sites.dc.__msdcs.mydomain.local_ points to *server3.mydomain.local*.
2. **Verifying DNS entries with `nslookup`.** `nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._udp.mydomain.local` returns entries for *server3* and *server4*—nothing about *server1*.
3. **Cleaning up metadata.** After using `ntdsutil` to clean up metadata as described [in this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736378%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), the `ntdsutil` command `list servers in site` returns only two entries, which both look OK:

   1. *0 - CN=SERVER4,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=local*
   2. *1 - CN=SERVER3,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=local*
4. **Deleting *server1* from Active Directory Sites and Services.** After demoting *server1*, I noticed it remained in Active Directory Sites and Services, although it was no longer listed as a global catalog. I deleted it according to the instructions in [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216364).
5. **Transferring operations master roles to *server3*.** Operations master roles are a bit beyond my ken, but I used `ntdsutil` to transfer them all to *server3* this morning. There were no errors, but reboots and tests showed that *server1* was still doing all the authentication.
6. **Reregistering with DNS and restarting *netlogon*.** A forum post suggested running `ipconfig /registerdns` and `net stop netlogon && net start netlogon` on the new servers to resolve a related issue. It didn't seem to help.
7. **Ensuring that the winning GPO on the new domain controllers enables auditing for logon and account logon events.**

## Other Leads

- The same problem is described in [this series of forum posts](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1753586). There's no resolution.
- It's also described in [this question on Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Active_Directory/Q_27579176.html). The comment marked as an answer reads, "If the its [sic] not a DC anymore, then there is no way it can be processing any authentication requests." That would be my reaction, but running `dcdiag` on *server1* confirms that *server1* doesn't consider itself a DC. Yet it's still the only server authenticating everybody.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a file server - are users connecting to it to get access to files? That's likely what you're seeing. Those would show up in the security logs.

Post some log entries (in their entirety - text dump or screenshot) from server1 that is showing the behavior you're concerned about.

/Edit - Thanks for confirming. Logon Type 3 is "Network." Most often seen when accessing shared files or printers on the computer that logged the event.

Comment: Thanks—I uploaded screenshots of the servers' security logs to imgur in an edit. Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upload images, so the link is spelled out in text.

Comment: The odd thing to me is that only _server1_ logs anything about logons and logoffs. I agree that those should show up on a file server, but don't DCs log them when users are authenticated?

Comment: Log entries in their entirety, please. Show the actual log event with all text, not a list of all the log entries, from server1.

Comment: Edited my post to add two sample logs from server1.

Comment: Edited my answer from tentative to positive.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get that _server1_ still needs to authenticate users before it can serve them files, but why aren't our actual domain controllers logging user logons from workstations? We're setting up a content filter (iBoss) that hooks domain controllers' user authentication events. The technician remoted into _server3_ and _server4_ and told me he didn't see any authentication events there but that _server1_ was still processing authentication. Since I plan to decommission _server1_ soon, I'd like to install the filter hook on the two new DCs and leave the old one untouched.

Comment: OK, so that's a new question, FYI - I've answered why you're seeing login events on a member server. It's probably because you're not auditing the correct events on the new domain controllers. You can change this with the proper settings in a GPO that applies to the OU containing the domain controllers.

Comment: Good point—I realize I worded the question wrong. The winning GPO on those other DCs does set those events to be audited on success ("Audit account logon events", "Audit logon events"), but none of those events shows up. I'll try setting it to include logging on failure also.

Comment: Is the usual practice here to accept your answer (since it does answer my original question) and create a second question?

Comment: Yes it is. Make sure to take the time to read the "help" link in the header bar.

Comment: Quick comment for any readers with the problem of new DCs not logging audit events: It turns out that corrupt audit.csv files were overriding the Group Policy audit settings [as described here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/087e4501-976e-480f-b924-2a05f9c92417/something-resets-group-policy-settings). After deleting the CSV files and running `auditpol /clear` and `gpupdate /force` on the new DCs, all is working. I owe @mfinni for pointing me in the direction of GPO audit settings when I was on all kinds of wild goose chases in troubleshooting!

Comment: Sounds good - glad you got that down. You'll definitely want to spend some time reading up on the care and feeding of domain controllers, best practices, etc. MS has a lot of good articles and training available, too.

Answer (score 2):

A demoted DC will in no way continue to authenticate domain logons. What you are seeing is *local* logon events. When you log onto a member server w/ domain credential, you will see logon events locally, plus corresponding credential validation events on DC.

When you log onto member server with local credential, you still see logon events locally, but won't see any credential validation events on DC.

Comment: Exactly right—it turned out that the demoted DC was logging authentication for file shares only. What confused me was that the new DCs weren't logging authentication events _at all_. The problem ended up being that the _audit.csv_ files on the new domain controllers were corrupt, but following the instructions on deleting  those files in [these TechNet posts](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/087e4501-976e-480f-b924-2a05f9c92417/something-resets-group-policy-settings) resolved that.